# Easy Way of Configuring a C++ Application Build

Tags: c++, build, cmake

Some people use autotools, some write makefiles, some claim the best way to configure a C++ build is to use CMake.

I'm looking into some CMake files, however it seems like there is so much to be written to get the easiest configuration using some external libraries like boost, or something else.

I've been looking carefully at e.g. SOCI CMake files (available at http://sourceforge.net/p/soci/code-0/ci/a0c04683595a1c7c3d442c9cc8b3ec6804062f31/tree/src/cmake/) and it seems like there is quite a huge amount of code.

Is that possible to configure a C++ application in quite easier way? I just want to build a C++ application, include some directories, include some libraries. What's more, I'd like to build it on different machines.

Comment: So how do you build it on another machine? You run IDE there?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest CMakeList (including Boost) could be just this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyProject)

find_package(Boost 1.48.0 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(MyExeTarget source1.cpp source2.cpp header1.h header2.h)
```

If you are using parts of Boost which need linking, you could do it like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyProject)

find_package(Boost 1.48.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(MyExeTarget source1.cpp source2.cpp header1.h header2.h)

target_link_libraries(MyExeTarget ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

These are just simple examples to get you started. Look into the CMake documentation of `FindBoost` for more on using Boost with CMake.